# Can I express `T =:= obj.MyType forSome { val obj :MyClass }`, either as type bounds or through givens in Scala 3?

Tags: type-inference, implicit, existential-type, scala-3, given

Lets say I have a unary evidence type constructor

```scala
  class MyEvidence[T]
  object MyEvidence {
    //statically provable implicit/given values for various type arguments.
  }
```

Now let us have urelated classes

```scala
  trait MyClass { type MyType; val myVal :Box[MyType] }
  class Box[T]
```

Lets us also assume that I not only know for a fact that a given `MyEvidence[obj.MyType]` exists or any `obj :MyClass`, but I can also construct it statically, without referencing `obj`, as a parameterless `given` value.

**Problem**:

1. In code, somewhere I have an `obj :MyClass` (such that I have no bounds on `obj.MyType`).
2. Lets assume I have an implicit conversion `Box[T] => Gizmo[T]` if an implicit `MyEvidence[T]` exists (the use case for that evidence).

How can I provide the needed `MyEvidence[obj.T]`, so that the conversion from point 2 exists?

I didn't minimize the question by replacing `myVal :Box[MyType]` with `myVal :MyType` (and the conversion to `T => Gizmo[T]` in case type inference works differently for type parameters and types of values (a hunch that the problem, as defined, may be easier).

Comment: You could make `obj` an implicit, something like `given obj: MyClass = ...` and then `given summonEvidence(using obj: MyClass): MyEvidence[obj.T] = ...`

Comment: No I cannot. Its not some globally calculated value existing only as evidence; it is part of the model.